# Codemodel Java Library - Initializing 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, sun-codemodel

Just trying to declare and initialize a 2D array using the codemodel library by Sun but I'm having some issues. I've tried:

```
JBlock.decl(model.LONG.array().array(), "arrayName", JExpr.newArray(model.LONG, n));
```

which outputs:

```
long[][] arrayName = new long[ n ] ;
```

But I can't seem to find a way to fill in the last [ ]. I've tried several variations.

To be more specific, I need to be able to initialize with something like:

```
(int) Math.sqrt(array.length);
```

JExpr.ref() doesn't seem to work for this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

how about using

```
JExpr.newArray(model.LONG.array(), n)
```

as the last argument.

Comment: this creates the new [], thanks. going to experiment with it.

Comment: what does it output ?

Comment: it outputs new long[n][]; unsure how to fill in the dimension of the inner arrays

Comment: well, i actually thought that is what you need from your question. Note that `long[][] arrayName = new long[n][]` is a valid java array declaration and compiles fine. It defines `n-sized` array of long[]. Each of the element of this array can be declared later, and could, in fact be different length, for example : arrayName[0] = new long[3]; arrayName[1] = new long[1]; // another size. But probably you know that already

Comment: initializing them later looks a little messy. was hoping to save the code by being able to add in that one digit. im new to this so maybe theres something im missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
JBlock.decl(model.LONG.array().array(), "arrayName", JExpr.ref("[n][n]"));
```

Comment: this doesnt work for more complicated entries like:(int) Math.sqrt(array.length)

Comment: @s990x well, it will work if you convert it to string first and then create your argument to `JExpr.ref`

Comment: any idea how to initialise the same. what i mean is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55790450/how-to-initialise-a-2d-array-using-codemodel