# How to initialise a 2D array using CodeModel

Tags: sun-codemodel, jcodemodel

I need to initialise a 2d array like below

```
     Object[][] someName = {
                             {"param1","param2","param3"}, 
                             {"param4","param5","param6"}
                            };
```

I tried like

```
    JExpression exp = JExpr.newArray(codeModel.ref(String.class)).add(JExpr.lit("param1").add(JExpr.lit("param2"));

    methodBlock.decl(JMod.NONE, codeModel.ref(Object.class).array().array(), dataProviderName, exp);
```

but it initilases 1d array,

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be exactly the same, but the following code initializes the example 2d array:

```
JDefinedClass testClass = codeModel._class("TestClass");

JMethod runme = testClass.method(JMod.PUBLIC, codeModel.VOID, "runme");
JBlock methodBlock = runme.body();

JExpression exp = JExpr.newArray(codeModel.ref(String.class).array())
    .add(JExpr.newArray(codeModel.ref(String.class))
                        .add(JExpr.lit("param1")).add(JExpr.lit("param2")).add(JExpr.lit("param3")))
    .add(JExpr.newArray(codeModel.ref(String.class))
                        .add(JExpr.lit("param4")).add(JExpr.lit("param5")).add(JExpr.lit("param6")));

methodBlock.decl(JMod.NONE, codeModel.ref(Object.class).array().array(), "someName", exp);
```

This generates the following, which explicitly declares the inner arrays:

```
public class TestClass {


    public void runme() {
        Object[][] someName = new String[][] {new String[] {"param1", "param2", "param3"}, new String[] {"param4", "param5", "param6"}};
    }

}
```

The code you tried was almost correct, you just needed to declare the array within the `newArray()` call: `JExpr.newArray(codeModel.ref(String.class).array())`